# sphinx search error when keyword contains symbol

Tags: mysql, sql, search, sphinx

I try to search in the manuscript table contain some data like '100021/hello', '199900/hello' etc.

```
 search -c /etc/sphinx/sphinx.conf 100021/hello
```

it shows index error, but when i try to search 100021 or hello,it can return right result.

```
 search -c /etc/sphinx/sphinx.conf 100021
 search -c /etc/sphinx/sphinx.conf hello
```

It seems sphinx can't recognize '/' in during searching?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue isn't with sphinx it's with your shell. Quote your input.

`search -c /etc/sphinx/sphinx.conf '100021/hello'`

Also the `search` command is just a testing tool. If you need to code against sphinx you should use the API in whatever language you're coding in.

Comment: thanks, but when i use search -c /etc/sphinx/sphinx.conf '100021/hello' it still shows index 'tablename' search error: .

Comment: when i just type search -c /etc/sphinx/sphinx.conf / it also shows index error

Comment: I agree, try using the real API. Avoid `search` tool, its broken